# How to putExtra in FragmentTransaction Android SDK 21

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have converted my app from activity views to fragment, but I don't know how to pass the extra info to my new fragment. Here I create a new fragment from another fragment.

This was the old working code

```
           Launch a new Activity to display the selected sensor
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SensorViewFragment.class);

           // Push the sensor index to the new Activity
           intent.putExtra(SensorViewFragment.SENSOR_INDEX_EXTRA, position);

           // Start the activity
           startActivity(intent);*/
```

And this is the new code in which I don't know how to putExtra

```
    // Set a listener to respond to list item clicks
    sensorListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // Create new fragment and transaction
            Fragment newFragment = new SensorViewFragment();
            // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended solution is to use an arguments `Bundle`. That way the data, as with your old extras, is automatically retained on a configuration change, in the recent-tasks list, etc.

Google's typical approach is to use a factory method (`newInstance()`) on the fragment class to handle packaging data into the arguments `Bundle`.

For example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments), I am creating fragments for a `ViewPager`. I want to pass the `position` (page number) into the fragments, so the fragments can use that in the UI.

On my fragment class (`EditorFragment`), I have a `newInstance()` factory method that puts the supplied `position` into the arguments `Bundle`, and I use the value in my `onCreateView()` method via `getArguments()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012-14 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.pager;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditorFragment extends Fragment {
  private static final String KEY_POSITION="position";

  static EditorFragment newInstance(int position) {
    EditorFragment frag=new EditorFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);
    EditText editor=(EditText)result.findViewById(R.id.editor);
    int position=getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);

    editor.setHint(String.format(getString(R.string.hint), position + 1));

    return(result);
  }
}
```

When I want to create an instance of the fragment, I just use the factory method (`EditorFragment.newInstance(position)`).

Comment: Thanks ! I see that Android Studio have generated that code in fragments, but how do you call the new fragment and pass the parameter?

Comment: @MarioM: Where you have `new SensorViewFragment()`, replace it with `SensorViewFragment.newInstance(position)`, after having implemented a `newInstance()` method.

Comment: I have this: Fragment newFragment = new SensorViewFragment.newInstance(position);  and I get a compilation error that the newInstance symbol cannot be found and I have the newInstance implemented in SensorViewFragment...  Also google recommends placing the fragments in a stack, what about that? Thanks !

Comment: @MarioM: Sorry, I meant replace *all* of `new SensorViewFragment()` with `SensorViewFragment.newInstance(position)`. That would give you `Fragment newFragment = SensorViewFragment.newInstance(position);`. What you have is not valid Java syntax. "Also google recommends placing the fragments in a stack, what about that?" -- I do not really know how to answer a question of "what about that", and I am not aware of this recommendation. You can put `FragmentTransactions` on the *back stack*, if you want the BACK button to reverse the transaction.

Comment: very strange, even intellisense sees newInstance implementation but after write it show with red, like it does not exist. I also did a clean and rebuild, but the same result.

Comment: I have changed the code to this and now it works:                                 SensorViewFragment newFragment = new SensorViewFragment();                
                newFragment.newInstance(position);

Comment: @MarioM: `newInstance()` is supposed to be a `static` method -- see the code in my answer.